# How many SAVEPOINTS are allowed in Oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

I came to know about savepoint in SQL to roll back to a specific transaction point. But there is no clue of how many savepoints can we create? Does a savepoint create extra burden on database!

Comment: I don't think they have an extra cost as they only store the SCN corresponding to the state the database is in. http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/transact.htm#CNCPT1121

Answer (score 1):

A simple test proves that the limit of savepoint number is big enough to cover any practical usage. It's most likely just limit of resources, UNDO tablespace.

```
HUSQVIK@HQ_PDB_TCP> CREATE TABLE test1 (val NUMBER);

Table created.

HUSQVIK@HQ_PDB_TCP> BEGIN
  2    FOR i IN 1..100000 LOOP
  3  INSERT INTO test1 VALUES (dbms_random.value);
  4  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SAVEPOINT s' || i;
  5    END LOOP;
  6  END;
  7  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

HUSQVIK@HQ_PDB_TCP> SELECT count(*) FROM test1;

  COUNT(*)
----------
    100000

1 row selected.

HUSQVIK@HQ_PDB_TCP> ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT s99999;

Rollback complete.

HUSQVIK@HQ_PDB_TCP> SELECT count(*) FROM test1;

  COUNT(*)
----------
     99999

1 row selected.

HUSQVIK@HQ_PDB_TCP> ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT s1;

Rollback complete.

HUSQVIK@HQ_PDB_TCP> SELECT count(*) FROM test1;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         1

1 row selected.

HUSQVIK@HQ_PDB_TCP>
```

Comment: I don't think that just _declaring_ a SAVEPOINT even use UNDO - only the changes that are done will generate UNDO (and the savepoint don't increase the UNDO size as far as I can tell - but I have no reference for that)

Comment: You're most likely right. Tried to find difference in undo usage when using savepoints compared to simple transaction but it seems the same so I expect the savepoints are only in-UGA memory reference to specific snapshot that savepoint is created at. I meant the UNDO because this will be most likely the resource that will be the first depleted just because of uncommitted changes done.

Answer (score 0):

I know that on Oracle 7 the default was 5 and it could be raised to 255 by setting the Oracle SAVEPOINTS initialization parameters. But after that i never had a problem.